# Apple Clang gives error when using bracket initialization, while g++ and ordinary Clang works

Tags: c++, macos, clang++

This code example from learncpp.com doesn't work on Apple Clang 13.0.0 while working on both ordinary Clang and g++ from Homebrew.

### Code

```
#include <iostream>

int getValueFromUser()
{
    std::cout << "Enter an integer: ";
    int input{};
    std::cin >> input;

    return input;
}

void printDouble(int value)
{
    std::cout << value << " doubled is: " << value * 2 << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    printDouble(getValueFromUser());

    return 0;
}
```

### Error

```
main.cpp:6:11: error: expected ';' at end of declaration
        int input{};
                 ^
                 ;
1 error generated.
```

Does Apple Clang have no support for initializations by brackets? I'm really puzzled right now.

Comment: You probably need to turn on C++11 (or newer) via a compiler flag

Comment: Are you compiling with `-std=c++11` or newer?

Answer (score 4):

Yeah, seems like Apple Clang's default standard is super old. When I added `-std=c++20` as a flag it compiled.